# Swift: define position of CIFilter CISourceOverCompositing inputImage

Tags: swift, xcode, cifilter, ciimage

i have a simple filter combining 2 CIImages.

```
let combinedFilter2 = CIFilter(name: "CISourceOverCompositing")!
        combinedFilter2.setValue(inputImage, forKey: "inputImage")
        combinedFilter2.setValue(combinedFilter.outputImage!, forKey: "inputBackgroundImage")
```

the inputImage is very small, so it looks like a view-in-view. 
Is there any possibility to "change the position" of that smaller image? It is actually allways on the bottom-left
I'm working with Swift 5

Answer (score 0):

Welcome!

You can apply a transformation to the image in order to translate/scale/rotate it:

```
let movedImage = inputImage.transformed(by: CGAffineTransform(translationX: 200, y: 300))
```

You can combine multiple `CGAffineTransforms` to achieve different changes in geometry.